# Stubbing vs Mocking in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, stub

I'm want to mock or stub a function for testing. Not sure if I have the terminology right so correct me if I'm wrong, but I understand a mock as using a mocking library similar to [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) to create a fake object and has expectations about what parameters it will receive and what what it will return, etc. This seems a bit of overkill to me since all I want is the mocked/stubbed method to do is return a set value.

I think of stubbing as just 'mocking without a library', like the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3909942/1393498). From what I can see, this is exactly what I want. It's light and simple and you don't have to mess around with all the options of mocking for the simple cases.

My question is, **is it safe to do this?** The question above seems to be overwriting the in memory representation of a method, and it just doesn't seem right. Is this accepted by the python community? Or is it encouraged to use a proper mocking library all the time?

**EDIT** What kind of horrible things would happen if you didn't reassign the method in the finally block, as the linked answer states?

Comment: To check to see if your test is safe, write another test to test your mocking. Nothing like metatesting!

Comment: Actually, what you describe (an object returning a set value) is exactly what the built-in mock library does, as you can see from the doc page you link to.

Comment: the main commonly accepted difference between a mock and a stub is that a stub returns data the test needs to pass and can never cause a test to fail. A mock is used to verify expectations on interactions between different components. Both mocking and stubbing can be done with out a library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason I wanted to stub the method myself was so that I wouldn't have to worry about a mock and go through setting it up. However I found [this blog post](http://www.toptal.com/python/an-introduction-to-mocking-in-python) which shows an excellent way to use the `mock` library with annotations making it a lot easier than creating an instance of `Mock` manually. Here is an excerpt:

rm.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import os.path

def rm(filename):
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        os.remove(filename)
```

rmtest.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from mymodule import rm

import mock
import unittest

class RmTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('mymodule.os.path')
    @mock.patch('mymodule.os')
    def test_rm(self, mock_os, mock_path):
        # set up the mock
        mock_path.isfile.return_value = False

        rm("any path")

        # test that the remove call was NOT called.
        self.assertFalse(mock_os.remove.called, "Failed to not remove the file if not present.")

        # make the file 'exist'
        mock_path.isfile.return_value = True

        rm("any path")

        mock_os.remove.assert_called_with("any path")
```