# How do I write a function that returns another function?

Tags: python, function, functional-programming, currying

In Python, I'd like to write a function `make_cylinder_volume(r)` which returns another function. That returned function should be callable with a parameter `h`, and return the volume of a cylinder with height `h` and radius `r`.

I know how to return *values* from functions in Python, but how do I return *another function*?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245192/what-are-first-class-objects

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Try this, using Python:

```
import math
def make_cylinder_volume_func(r):
    def volume(h):
        return math.pi * r * r * h
    return volume
```

Use it like this, for example with `radius=10` and `height=5`:

```
volume_radius_10 = make_cylinder_volume_func(10)
volume_radius_10(5)
=> 1570.7963267948967
```

Notice that returning a function was a simple matter of defining a new function inside the function, and returning it at the end - being careful to pass the appropriate parameters for each function. FYI, the technique of returning a function from another function is known as [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Comment: So the `10` you passed in is stored somewhere? When does it get garbage-collected?

Comment: @sudo take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)

Comment: If you came here and also want to do type-hinting, go here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42705709/how-to-type-hint-a-function-that-returns-a-function

Answer (score 24):

Using lambdas, also known as anonymous functions, you can abstract out the `volume` function inside the `make_cylinder_volume_func` to a single line. In no way different from Óscar López's answer, the solution using lambda is still in a sense 'more functional'.

This is how you can write the accepted answer using a lambda expression:

```
import math
def make_cylinder_volume_fun(r):
    return lambda h: math.pi * r * r * h
```

And then call as you'd any other curried function:

```
volume_radius_1 = make_cylinder_volume_fun(1)
volume_radius_1(1) 
=> 3.141592653589793
```

Comment: I realise you are answering what was requested, but for the sake of my understanding, if `lambda h:` was removed would the function work the same?

Comment: @schoon No it won't work in this case. This is actually a very interesting case to highlight the idea of 'variable scoping' and function currying (which basically relies on varibale scoping). The reason why it doesn't work (in my example) is because the `return` will try to evaluate the result before returning, and because it's a bunch of variables, it will return some float value (try returning a function and it will work). `lambda` tellsl that the following code shouldn't be evaluated and also that the scope of variable r will be preserved in functions returned by `make_cylinder..`.

Answer (score 10):

Just want to point out that you can do this with pymonad

```
 import pymonad 

 @pymonad.curry
 def add(a, b):
     return a + b

 add5 = add(5)
 add5(4)
 9
```

Comment: ```from functools import partial
add5 = partial(add, 5)```
Does exactly the same

Answer (score 3):

I know I am too late to the party, but I think you might find this solution interesting.

```py
from math import pi
from functools import partial

def cylinder_volume(r, h):
    return pi * r * r * h

make_cylinder_with_radius_2 = partial(cylinder_volume, 2)
make_cylinder_with_height_3 = partial(cylinder_volume, h=3)

print(cylinder_volume(2, 3))            # 37.6991118431
print(make_cylinder_with_radius_2(3))   # 37.6991118431
print(make_cylinder_with_height_3(2))   # 37.6991118431
```

Here is [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial) about how `partial` works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one massive example which covers many of single multiple argument cases in one function

```
def maths(var='NA'):
if var.lower() == 'add':
    def add(*args):
        return "Sum is : "+str(sum(args))
    return add
elif var.lower() == 'substract':
    def substract(a,b):
        if a>b:
            return "Difference is : "+str(a-b)
        else:
            return "Difference is : "+str(b-a)
    return substract
elif var.lower() == 'multiply':
    def multiply(*args):
        temp = 1
        for x in args:
            temp = temp*x
        return "multiplication is : "+str(temp)
    return multiply
elif var.lower() == 'divide':
    def divide(a,b):
        return "Division is : "+str(a/b)
    return divide
else:
    print("Please choose one of given operations: 'add','substract','multiply','divide'")
```

Here first call the maths function with the required operation and then use the returned function for the actual calculation

Answer (score -1):

Function return another function by simple example

```
def outer_func():
  def inner_func():
    print('inside inner func')
  return inner_func
outer_func()()
```

Answer (score -2):

## Here is one massive example which covers many of single multiple argument cases in one function

```
def maths(var='NA'):
  if var.lower() == 'add':
    return lambda *args : f"Sum is {sum(args)}"
  elif var.lower() == 'substract':
    return lambda a,b: str(a-b) if a>b else (b-a)
  elif var.lower() == 'multiply':
    # return lambda *args: (lambda x:x[0]*x[1:])(args)
    return lambda *args: 1 if not args else (lambda x: x[0] if len(x) == 1 else x[0]*c(*x[1:]))(args)
  elif var.lower() == 'divide':
    # return lambda *args: 1 if not args else (lambda x: x[0] if len(x) == 1 else x[0] / c(*x[1:]))(args)
    return lambda a,b : a/b if a>b else "Not possible"
  else:
    print("Please choose one of given operations: 'add','substract','multiply','divide'")
a = maths(var='add')
print(a(2,5,3))
b = maths(var='substract')
print(b(2,5))
c = maths(var='multiply')
print(c(7,5,9))
c = maths(var='divide')
print(c(7,5))
```