# How to type hint a function that returns a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

Let's say I have the following code:

```
def validator(blacklist: list=['heck', 'muffins']):

    def f(questionable_word: str) -> bool:
        return questionable_word in blacklist

    return f

validator_british = validator(['pish'])
validator_british('pish')  # returns True
validator_british('heck')  # returns False
```

My question is how do I type-hint the `validator` function such that it indicates a function is returned, and specifically a function that takes a `str` and returns a `bool`? The `f` function's signature is:

```
def f(questionable_word: str) -> bool
```

What do I put in the `???` place for `validator`?

```
validator(blacklist: list=['heck', 'muffins']) -> ???:
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) is what you want:

```
validator(blacklist: list=['heck', 'muffins']) -> Callable[[str], bool]:
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks!