# How do i get the prints under main to show up in final output

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.x, formatting

Im trying to create a chart for radii that the output looks like this.

```
Radius           Area            Circumference
1.000             3.142           6.283
2.000            ...               ...
```

The prints under main do not show up at all. Any suggestions on how I might fix this? Im using python 3.4.

```
def main():
    print('Radius\tArea\tCircumference')
    print('-----------------------------')


for Radius in range(1 , 11):
    round (3)

    Area = (Radius)**2*3.14
    Circumference =  (Radius)*2*(3.14)
    a = Radius
    b = Area
    c = Circumference
    d = round(a, 3)
    e = round(b, 3)
    f = round(c, 3)

    print ('{:2d}{:10.2f}{:10.2f}'.format(d, (e), (f)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`main()` has no special meaning in Python. It's just a function like any other; if you want it to run, you need to explicitly call it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the main() function. For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130958/what-does-it-mean-to-call-a-function-in-python):-

```
def add(a,b):
    return a + b 

//Calling explicitly
answer = add(4,7)
print answer
```

> Output:-11