# Checking that array doesn't contain negative numbers, and running function again if it does

Tags: python, arrays, numbers, output

My task today is to create a way for checking if a function's output contains negative numbers, and if it does, then I must run the function until it contains no negative numbers.

I'll post the full code later in the post, but this is my attempt at a solution:

```
def evecs(matrixTranspose):
     evectors = numpy.linalg.eig(matrixTranspose)[1][:,0]
     return evectors


if any(x<0 for x in evectors) == False:
    print(evectors)
```

evecs() is my function, and evectors is the output array, but I only want to print evectors if there are no negative entries in it. I also want to later add that if there *are* negative entries in it, the code should run the evecs function again until it finds an evectors that has no negative entries.

However, whenever I run it I get the error:

> global name evectors is not defined

Here's a link to my code, and the full output from the iPython console. http://pastebin.com/3Bk9h1gq

Thanks!

Comment: whitespace is extremely important in python. check your indentions

Comment: Do not compare boolean values, but use the natural way: `if not any(x<0 for x in evectors):`

Comment: Do you understand [how to use a function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19130958/3821804)?

Answer (score 3):

You have not declared the variable `evectors` other than within the scope of your function `evecs`.

```
evectors = evecs(matrixTranspose)

if any(x<0 for x in evectors) == False:
    print(evectors)
```

**EDIT**

There are several issues:

1. Indentation is VERY important in Python. `MarkovChain` and  `evecs` are two seperate functions. You had your `evacs` function indented an extra level in, embeddeding it within `MarkovChain`.
2. `MarkovChain` should return `matrixTransponse` if you plan to use it in another function call.
3. As a result of the above issue, your function call to `MarkovChain` needs to be assigned to a variable, `matrixTranponse`, otherwise you will get an error stating that `matrixTranspose` is not defined when you make your function call to `evecs` with it.
4. Since the initialization of the variable `matrixTranspose` isn't set until the function call to `MarkovChain` is completed, the remainder of your logic will need to be re-ordered.

I have applied all the above changes below and added comments to the changed areas:

```
def MarkovChain(n,s) :
    """

    """
    matrix = []
    for l in range(n) :
        lineLst = []
        sum = 0
        crtPrec = precision
        for i in range(n-1) :
            val = random.randrange(crtPrec)
            sum += val
            lineLst.append(float(val)/precision)
            crtPrec -= val
        lineLst.append(float(precision - sum)/precision)
        matrix2 = matrix.append(lineLst)
    print("The intial probability matrix.")    
    print(tabulate(matrix))
    matrix_n = numpy.linalg.matrix_power(matrix, s)  
    print("The final probability matrix.")
    print(tabulate(matrix_n))
    matrixTranspose = zip(*matrix_n)

    return matrixTransponse    # issue 2

# issue 1
def evecs(matrixTranspose):
    evectors = numpy.linalg.eig(matrixTranspose)[1][:,0]
    return evectors

matrixTranponse = MarkovChain(4, 10000000000)     # issue 3

# issue 4
evectors = evecs(matrixTranspose)

if any(x<0 for x in evectors) == False:
    print(evectors)
```

Comment: Yup. The OP defines the function, never seems to use it or store any output from it, and then tries to access results.

Comment: That's.. quite an embarrassing mistake. My bad. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I went ahead and implemented it, and even though there aren't any errors, I still am not getting any output for the evectors part. Here's my full code, along with the output that I'm getting. http://pastebin.com/u5qNF7PP Where is my mistake?