# Python if( ): vs if:

Tags: python, function, if-statement

On Code Academy there is this course where in the example they show

```
def speak(message):
    return message

if happy():
    speak("I'm happy!")
elif sad():
    speak("I'm sad.")
else:
    speak("I don't know what I'm feeling.")
```

The above example will **NOT** be related to the rest of the code I show. That was just an example for the `if` statement. Now I was under the impression that when ever writing an `if` statement it had to end in an `():`like the above example.

However when doing the assignments this does not work:

```
def shut_down(s):
    if s == "yes"():
        return "Shutting down"
    elif s == "no"():
        return "Shutdown aborted"
    else:
        return "Sorry"
```

However this works:

```
def shut_down(s):
    if s == "yes":
        return "Shutting down"
    elif s == "no":
        return "Shutdown aborted"
    else:
        return "Sorry"
```

My question is how come the `()` is not needed next to the `"yes"` and `"no`" but `:`is still needed. I thought whenever writing an `if` statement it will automatically have to end with `():`. In that very first example, that's how it is shown. Do you understand my confusion.

Comment: No, that's not the case. See [what the official tutorial says about the `if` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements).

Comment: It looks like you have a fundamental misunderstanding about [functions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) and [`if` statements](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements).

Comment: Happy and sad are probably [functions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19131217/5031339)

Comment: @chrisaycock I think you're thinking of a different kind of assignment than the OP

Answer (score 5):

In the example given, `happy()` and `sad()` are functions, and as such require parentheses. The `if` itself does not need parentheses at the end (and it shouldn't have them)

Answer (score 4):

No, `if` has nothing to do with `()`

`happy` is a function. `happy()` is a call to that function. So, `if happy():` tests if the `happy` function returns true when called.

In other words, `if happy(): speak("I'm happy!")` is equivalent to

```
result_of_happy = happy()
if result_of_happy:
    speak("I'm happy!")
```

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned `happy() / sad()` are functions so they require `()`. In example two of your question you are comparing your value to the string `"yes"` because it is a string it does not require `()`.

Within an `if` statement you can use parentheses to make the code more readable and ensure certain operations are evaluated before others.

```
if (1+1)*2 == 4:
    print 'here'
else:
    print 'there'
```

Differs from:

```
if 1+1*2 == 4:
    print 'here'
else:
    print 'there'
```

Answer (score 0):

Because string objects are not callable so what are you expecting then:

Then use `lambda` not that efficient tho:

```
def shut_down(s):
    if (lambda: s == "yes")():
        return "Shutting down"
    elif (lambda: s == "no")():
        return "Shutdown aborted"
    else:
        return "Sorry"
```