# Error = object(str) is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Car():
 def __init__(self,color,model):
  self.color=color
  self.model=model

Audi = Car("red","A4")

print(Audi.color())
print(Audi.model())
```

I'm getting a "string object is not callable" error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [what does it mean to call something in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130958/what-does-it-mean-to-call-a-function-in-python), one does not simply call a string.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the parentheses:

```
print(Audi.color) 
print(Audi.model)
```

since `model` and `color` are simple string attributes of `Car` rather than callable methods.

Comment: @user7083361 No problem. Don't forget to accept the solution if you are satisfied with it ;)