# 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fruits = ["APPLE","BANANA","GRAPES","ORANGE"]
prices = [80,45,60,50]


fru_prices = pd.DataFrame[fruits,prices]
```

> I am getting error while I am creating a Data Frame : 'type' object is
>   not subscriptable

Comment: `pd.DataFrame` is not a list but a method. So add the brackets `pd.DataFrame([fruits,prices])`

Comment: `pd.DataFrame` is a method and of type `'type'`. So, you are getting error as `'type' object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: But fruits names are in row wise how to make it column wise ?

Comment: Pandas has a great tutorial for beginners . Do go through that http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/bitbucket.org/hrojas/learn-pandas/raw/master/lessons/01%20-%20Lesson.ipynb and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html

Comment: @sk jainmiah : check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `DataFrame` then as an argument do the list:

```
fru_prices=pd.DataFrame([fruits,prices])
```

And as you want to transpose do:

```
fru_prices=fru_prices.T
```

And need columns so:

```
fru_prices.columns=['fruits','prices']
```

Then `fru_prices` is what you want

Actually you can do this all in one-line:

```
fru_prices=pd.DataFrame([fruits,prices],index=['fruit','prices']).T
```

Related:

> See:[What does it mean to "call" a function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130958/what-does-it-mean-to-call-a-function-in-python)

Comment: Will it be faster when I execute it with lot of data ?

Comment: Yup it will, pandas is always fast

Comment: Thank you sir, how to follow you ?

Comment: @skjainmiah Follow me, there's no way to do that on stackoverflow tho, but an accept and upvote makes me happy already :-), hahaha.

Answer (score 1):

`pd.DataFrame` is a method and of type `'type'`. So, you are getting error as `'type' object is not subscriptable`. So,

```
fru_prices = pd.DataFrame([fruits,prices])
```

Comment: But fruits names are in row wise how to make it column wise ?

Comment: @skjainmiah transpose the dataframe i.e `pd.DataFrame([fruits,prices]).T`

Answer (score 1):

Use below code as: pd.DataFrame is a method.
python : 3.6.2

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fruits = ["APPLE","BANANA","GRAPES","ORANGE"]
prices = [80,45,60,50]


fru_prices =pd.DataFrame([fruits,prices])
fru_prices = fru_prices.set_index(0).T ##This entry conver it into row to column
print(fru_prices)
```

OutPut:

```
0   APPLE  80
1  BANANA  45
2  GRAPES  60
3  ORANGE  50
```

Check this and let us know in case of this code works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but Column Names are missing Sir.

Answer (score 1):

This error, i.e, 'type' object is not subscriptable, occurs when I am using square brackets.  Using parenthesis solves the problem.

Comment: When your answer is too short, you can send it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    fruits = ["APPLE","BANANA","GRAPES","ORANGE"]
    prices = [80,45,60,50]

    fru_prices = list(zip(fruits,prices))

    pd.DataFrame(data = fru_prices ,columns = ['fruits','prices'])

---------------------------------------------------------------------

    output :

    fruits  prices
 0  APPLE   80
 1  BANANA  45
 2  GRAPES  60
 3  ORANGE  50



> Python zip function takes iterable elements as input, and returns
> iterator. Now data will appear in column wise.
```

Comment: Why `zip` instead of pandas `T` method

Comment: When Pandas T is used we can transpose the data but  column headings are not printed, while zip  clearly represent the column names.

Comment: Well but..., how about mine?, okay but then use `index` instead of `columns`, (all in mine)

Comment: Thank you @U9-Forward . Your answer also works for me.

Comment: happy that i helped,