# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'function'

Tags: python

I am currently trying to add the the values of the dice rolls together to get the first player's score as you can see withins the two functions but keep getting the error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'function'.
I don't understand why it is not working so I hope someone could help me and tell me why it doesn't work

```
def D1P1(number_rolled1):
    FirstDice6 = random.randint (1, 6)
    print ("Rolling the first dice")
    time.sleep (2)
    print (('You rolled a '+str(FirstDice6)+' Player 1'))
    return (FirstDice6)

D1P1(number_rolled1)

def D2P1(number_rolled2):
    SecondDice6 = random.randint (1, 6)
    print ("Rolling the second dice")
    time.sleep (2)
    print (('You rolled a '+str(SecondDice6)+' Player 1'))
    return(1,6)

number_rolled2 = 0
D2P1(number_rolled2)


def player1score():
    score1 = (D1P1) + (D2P1)
    print (score1)
```

Comment: `(D1P1)` - That's not how you call functions

Comment: You call functions like `score1 = D1P1(3) + D1P1(5)` for example

Comment: because here - `score1 = (D1P1) + (D2P1)` you are not calling functions, you are trying to add two functions, and, as the error says, you cant add functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions `D1P1` and  `D2P1` weren't using the arguments supplied.
I'm not entirely sure of what you're trying to achieve, but here's a working version of your code that makes more sense:

```
import random
import time

def D1P1():
    FirstDice6 = random.randint (1, 6)
    print ("Rolling the first dice")
    time.sleep (2)
    print (('You rolled a '+str(FirstDice6)+' Player 1'))
    return FirstDice6

def D2P1():
    SecondDice6 = random.randint (1, 6)
    print ("Rolling the second dice")
    time.sleep (2)
    print ('You rolled a '+str(SecondDice6)+' Player 1')
    return SecondDice6

print(D1P1() + D2P1())
```

---

Reading:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm

---

Update:

Here's a smaller version:

```
import random, time
ordinal = lambda n: "%d%s" % (n,"tsnrhtdd"[(n/10%10!=1)*(n%10<4)*n%10::4])

def rolls(x):
    res = 0
    for x in range(1,x+1):
        roll = random.randint (1, 6)
        print ("Rolling the {} dice".format(ordinal(x)))
        time.sleep (2)
        print ('You rolled a {} Player 1'.format(roll))
        res+=roll
    return res
print(rolls(2))
```

[Demo](http://jdoodle.com/a/PRJ)

Comment: Just asking what is r1 and r2? Is it the number of rolls?

Comment: Yes roll, but your functions (`D1P1` and  D2P1`) weren't using the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [call your functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130958/what-does-it-mean-to-call-a-function-in-python), and use the return value.

```
score1 = D1P1(0) + D2P1(0)
```

See the python documentation for more details: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: I don't really understand, could you show me a example with my code?