# CSV data structure printing in messy format

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've exported an Excel into a CSV where all the columns and entires look correct and normal. However, when I put it into a data frame and print the head, the structure becomes very messy and unreadable due to columns being unstructured.

As you can see in the image, the values are not neatly under user_id.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZXZ3.jpg

I'm using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

then

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('../doc.csv', low_memory=False)

df1.head
```

Comment: Most of the code is missing, can you add it.

Comment: @v.coder sorry, just added it

Comment: @Goyo I'm not sure I follow? This is all the code which produce the code shown in the Imugur link

Comment: try `df1.head()`, `.head()` is a function and requires being called with `()`

Comment: @MichaelSilverstein that worked thanks a lot, I appreciate your help. However, can you explain why `()` is needed so I can remember for next time? It feels like such a small detail!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19130958/2142055

Comment: No problem! When you put `.head()` you are calling a function on `df1`. Without `()` you are just referencing the `head` method. This is different than if you did `df1.columns`, here `columns` is not a function it is just a class variable of `df1`. This article may help a bit: https://dev.to/ogwurujohnson/distinguishing-instance-variables-from-class-variables-in-python-81

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: Hello you forget the call () in head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this --- print the invocation of head.  Just saying .head isn't enough.

```
print(df1.head())
```