# Trying to Understand this bit of Python code on the topic of decorators

Tags: python, closures, decorator

[image: trying to understand this bit of code]
for some readability and searchability, here is the typed out code

```
def counter(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
       wrapper.count += 1
       return func (*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.count = 0 
    return wrapper

@counter
def foo():
   print('calling foo()')

foo()
foo()
print('foo() was called {} times.'.format(foo.count))
```

currently learning how decorator works...encounter this bit of code
couldn't understand`wrapper.count = 0`
and how when using the decorate in the following code, that the `wrapper.count = 2` but not reset to 0

does this have anything to do with closure?

I visited other post which contains similar problem. the answer wasn't that clear to me

can anyone explain the logic behind this code?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [this guide](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/) from Realpython will help?

Comment: It is recommended to paste a code snippet rather then a screenshot. Please see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, functions are [first-class objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23037519/are-functions-first-class-objects-in-python), which means that functions themselves are objects, and can be treated as such -- you can assign them to a variable, you can set attributes, etc.

So the line `wrapper.count = 0` sets the `count` attribute for the `wrapper` object to the integer `0`. The fact that `wrapper` is a function is irrelevant for now.

The way the `wrapper` function is defined, every time you call `wrapper`, the function increments its own `count` attribute.

Now, when you use `counter` as a decorator, the decorated function is replaced by the value that your decorator returned. It would be as if you did something like this:

```
def foo():
    print("Calling foo()")

def counter(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapper.count += 1
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.count = 0
    return wrapper

# These two lines are equivalent to decorating foo with @counter   
wrapping_func = counter(foo)
foo = wrapping_func
```

So when you call `foo()`, you're actually calling the `wrapper` function object that was returned when you decorated `foo` with `@counter` (i.e. `wrapping_func`). This `wrapper` does two things:

1. Increment its own `.count` attribute
2. Call the original `foo` function with whatever args you passed

Since you called `foo()` two times, the `.count` was incremented two times

Later, when you access `foo.count`, you're actually accessing the `count` attribute for the `wrapper` object that we talked about earlier (`wrapping_func.count`), which is `2`.

Comment: maybe a syntactic sugar version makes the connection with _counter_ a bit clearer: `@counter;
def foo(): pass;
foo();
foo();
print(foo.count)`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used python in a while myself, so I may be a bit rusty, but since there aren't any other answers, I'll see what I can do to help.

Functions in Python are first class, which means they are all actually classes under the hood. Think of `def wrapper` as declaring a class rather than a function. The only difference is that it only has one method and its constructor is outside the class. `wrapper.count = 0` is just serving as that constructor to let Python know that it has an extra property. It does look a little confusing to see that declared after the function though. Now that Python knows about `wrapper.count`, that property can be accessed in the method. `wrapper.count = 0` only runs once (as a constructor), but `wrapper.count += 1` runs as many times as you call `foo`. If there was another function decorated with `@counter`, it would have a different count than `foo`'s counter because they are different instances of the same class. You can access `foo.count` because it is not `foo` anymore. Now it is a separate instance of `counter` that happens to call `foo` inside of it.

That may not use the fancy, technically more correct, language, but hopefully that helps.