# How to randomly select functions within a function in python

Tags: python

I have two functions doing different operations but I would like them to be called in another function randomly.

eg.

```
def func1(): do something
def funct2(): do something else

def func3(): select funct1() or funct2() randomly
```

Comment: and what is the problem here?

Comment: I know how to use random or randint but couldn't do the same for functions

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Collect the functions in a list and randomly choose one of them (using [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice)) and call it!

```
>>> def f2():
        return 2

>>> def f1():
        return 1

>>> fns = [f1, f2]
>>> from random import choice
>>> choice(fns)()
1
>>> choice(fns)()
2
```

This is possible because Python functions are first class objects. Read up [this link on first class objects in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245192/what-are-first-class-objects).