# Add functions to a list but still be able to execute them

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm fairly new to python and coding in general. I'm making a builder with 4 possible building blocks. Building block a is mandatory but the other 3 are optional. So I want a user to be able to tell 'I want to use module b, c, d' or any combination of these. Additionally the choice of which block to use is randomized.

Right now i have it written down as 7 if elif else loops but I hope there is a cleaner way to do this.

```
import random

blocks_to_use = 10
useb = True
usec = False
used = True

def a():
    # build block a
    return # block_a

def b():
    # build block b
    return # block_b

def c():
    # build block c
    return # block_c

def d():
    # build block d
    return # block_d

def build():
    tower = ''
    if useb and not usec and not used:
        for block in range(blocks_to_use):
            tower = tower + random.choice((a(), b()))
    elif not useb and usec and not used:
        for block in range(blocks_to_use):
            tower = tower + random.choice((a(), c()))
    elif not useb and not usec and used:
        for block in range(blocks_to_use):
            tower = tower + random.choice((a(), d()))
    elif useb and usec and not used:
        for block in range(blocks_to_use):
            tower = tower + random.choice((a(), b(), c()))
    elif useb and not usec and used:
        for block in range(blocks_to_use):
            tower = tower + random.choice((a(), b(), d()))
    elif not useb and usec and used:
        for block in range(blocks_to_use):
            tower = tower + random.choice((a(), c(), d()))
    else:
        for block in range(blocks_to_use):
            tower = tower + random.choice((a(), b(), c(), d()))
    return tower
```

I was hoping I could make a function like modules_to_use which adds functions b/c/d as specified by the user to a list but I don't know how to do this

Comment: More specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916785/how-to-randomly-select-functions-within-a-function-in-python

Comment: @Berend you wrote: "Additionally the choice of which block to use is randomized." -- I think what you want to say here is the proportions per block (for instance to get 10 blocks, how many of a or b or c to include) to use in each tower combination to get the total of 10 ?  If not can you clarify this ?

Answer (score -1):

Based on the description given, I would go by the below. Call build() with any number of blocks as functions (further instruction can be defined within the function to perform the desired task).

```
import math
blocks_to_use = 10

def a():
    return 'a'
def b():
    return 'b'
def c():
    return 'c'
def d():
    return 'd'


def getrandomprops(all_blocks, maxsumofblocks):
    num_of_blocks={}
    ratio = math.floor(maxsumofblocks/len(all_blocks))
    [num_of_blocks.update({i:ratio}) for i in all_blocks]
    extra = maxsumofblocks-ratio*len(all_blocks)
    [num_of_blocks.update({k:num_of_blocks[k]+1}) for idx,k in enumerate(num_of_blocks) if idx<extra]
    return num_of_blocks

def build(*args):
    _blocks = [block for block in args]
    _blocks.insert(0, a())
    block_proportions = getrandomprops(_blocks, blocks_to_use)
    [print('Block: {} ------------> Number of blocks to use: {}\n'.format(k,v)) for k,v in block_proportions.items()]
```

To test this define number blocks (below I define b,c and d but you can use 1 or 2).

> ```
> b, c, d = b(), c(), d()
> build(b,c,d)
> ```

Results

> Block: a ------------> Number of blocks to use: 3
>
> Block: b ------------> Number of blocks to use: 3
>
> Block: c ------------> Number of blocks to use: 2
>
> Block: d ------------> Number of blocks to use: 2

Comment: The problem is these building blocks actually will contain actions that need to be performed

Comment: @Berend so it will help  me to be sure I made a useful contribution if you confirm whether the above code solves your issue.  Also the functions are there for any future actions that you want to add, such that instead of returning 'a', you can return the tasks defined in the function. The way to call build will still remain same.