# How it's possible to create a variable on function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributes

How it is possible to create variable on function in below example? Can anyone please explain about this possibility in `wrapper.count`?

```
def logging_decorator(func):
    def wrapper():
        wrapper.count += 1
        print "The function I modify has been called {0} times(s).".format(
              wrapper.count)
        func()
    wrapper.count = 0
    return wrapper

def a_function():
    print "I'm a normal function."

modified_function = logging_decorator(a_function)

modified_function()
# >> The function I modify has been called 1 time(s).
# >> I'm a normal function.

modified_function()
# >> The function I modify has been called 2 time(s).
# >> I'm a normal function.
```

Comment: Is your indentation 100% correct?

Comment: yes it is .. can you please explain about the logic behind creating a variable on function ? normally we will create properties on object right  which we defined in class that we made right ? is it similar to that ?

Comment: @Bee.. it wasn't correctly indented, actually (next time someone asks, *actually check*), but I have fixed it

Comment: thanks for correcting me.. sure i will do that next time

Comment: @Bee.. ah you see, so indentation changes everything. *DO* check next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is an object-oriented language through-and-through - a function is just another object instance * (also referred to as "first class objects" - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/245192/3001761)):

```
>>> def myfunc():
    pass

>>> type(myfunc)
<type 'function'>
```

and has a `__dict__` of its attributes:

```
>>> myfunc.__dict__
{}
```

Therefore you can add an attribute to a function, as you can to any other class instances with a `__dict__` **:

```
>>> myfunc.foo = "bar"
>>> myfunc.__dict__
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

---

Another example of this is the classic memoizer, where a `cache` dictionary attribute is added to the function returned by a decorator:

```
def memoize(f):
    def func(*args):
        if args not in func.cache:
            func.cache[args] = f(*args)
        return func.cache[args]
    func.cache = {}
    return func
```

---

* *This is not true of built-in functions, which are `<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>` - for example, you can't add an attribute to `max`.*

** *Not all instances have a `__dict__` - for example, instances of the built-in types like `int` and `str` don't, so you can't add attributes to those, either.*