# Timeit and Partials

Tags: python, partial, timeit, functools

Check this python code:

```
 from functools import partial
 def summer(x, y):
      return x+y

 >>>partial(summer, 1, 2)
 <functools.partial object at 0x10e648628>
```

However, when I pass in partial time timeit:

```
  import timeit
  min(timeit.repeat(partial(summer, 1, 2)))
```

It seems to evaluate summer with x=1 and y=2.

Am I understanding what's going on? Am I using timeit right? And how do I get partial to evaluate summer, when I pass values for every parameter?

EDIT: I added the below comment as part of this question for clarity.

My issue is that partial(summer, 1, 2) does not evaluate summer. So why does calling it inside of timeit.repeat evaluate summer?

Comment: `It seems to evaluate summer with x=1 and y=2.` That's what's supposed to happen, right?

Comment: Yes, this is the behavior-as-specified.  What behavior are you trying to produce?

Comment: My issue is that partial(summer, 1, 2) does not evaluate summer. So why does calling it inside of timeit.repeat evaluate summer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python `function` objects are ["first-class" objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/245192/190597). They can be passed as arguments to functions just like any other object. In this case,
`timeit.repeat` is being passed the function object `partial(summer, 1, 2)` so that later, inside of `repeat` the function object can be called and timed.

`partial(summer, 1, 2)` itself is another example of passing a function (`summer`) as an argument to another function (`partial`). It makes sense that you'd want to pass the function object since you don't want to call `summer` yet. Instead you want the function object returned by `partial` to have access to `summer` so it can be called later when that function object is called.

---

`partial(summer, 1, 2)` returns a function object:

```
In [36]: partial(summer, 1, 2)
Out[36]: <functools.partial at 0x7ff31f0bd3c0>
```

As you know, to call the function, you need to place parentheses after the function:

```
In [37]: partial(summer, 1, 2)()
Out[37]: 3
```

---

Normally when I use `timeit` I pass a statement `stmt` and setup to the `timeit` function as strings:

```
In [41]: func = partial(summer, 1, 2)

In [42]: timeit.repeat('func()', 'from __main__ import func')
Out[42]: [0.11481308937072754, 0.10448503494262695, 0.1048579216003418]
```

However, you are correct that it is also possible to pass a callable (such as a function object) as the first argument:

```
timeit.repeat(func)
```

`repeat` will call `func` and time the result. You can see how `repeat` handles this case by stepping through the code using a debugger like `pdb`:

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
timeit.repeat(func)
```

Inside the code for `timeit.py` [around line 140](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ac176a69d188/Lib/timeit.py#l131) you'll see:

```
    elif callable(stmt):
        self.src = None
        if isinstance(setup, str):
            _setup = setup
            def setup():
                exec(_setup, global_ns, local_ns)
```

which checks if `stmt`, the first argument is callable. If it is, then it sets `func` to `stmt`, and later calls `func`  ([source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ac176a69d188/Lib/timeit.py#l88)).

```
def inner(_it, _timer, _func=func):
    setup()
    _t0 = _timer()
    for _i in _it:
        _func()       # <--- The function call happens here
    _t1 = _timer()
    return _t1 - _t0
return inner
```

---

Comment: Let's say I have a callable I call s. s() works and returns a value as expected, but when I do timeit.repeat(s), it hangs forever. Any ideas?

Comment: There are many possible reasons. Without seeing your code this is pure speculation. Note however, that by default, if you don't set the `repeat` and `number` parameters, `timeit.repeat` will call the function 3 million times. (It calls `self.timeit` 3 times, and each call to `self.timeit` calls the function 1 million times). A trickier reason why `timeit.repeat(s)` may hang is if `s` mutates some global value (say, a list) and the duration of `s()` may grow as that global value grows...

Comment: It turned out to be that my code block takes a second to run once, so 1 million calls to that takes a long time. Thanks!