# Wtforms isinstance not working correctly

Tags: python, wtforms

Here's an example

```
import wtforms

isinstance(wtforms.StringField, wtforms.Field)
```

Why isinstance returns False?
If wtforms.StringField is inherited from the wtforms.Field, because in this case should return isinstanse True.
Why it returns False? How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isinstance` checks if *object* is an instance of *class type*. In you case, `wtforms.StringField` is a *class type* (which can act like an object because Python has [first-class everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245192/what-are-first-class-objects)), and has type `type`. You actually need `issubclass` for that.

I.e.:

```
>>> isinstance(OrderedDict(), dict)
True
>>> isinstance(OrderedDict, dict)
False
>>> isinstance(OrderedDict, type)
True
>>> issubclass(OrderedDict, dict)
True
```

`OrderedDict` is derived from `dict`. Thus, object of `OrderedDict()` **is instance of** `dict`, and `OrderedDict` **is subclass of** `dict`.