# Python: using variable as function name

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I aim to create a function wrapper across this statement:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
MonthNumber = np.array([1,1,2,4,5,6,5])
Data = np.array([1.1,3,.52,34,15,45,34])
Data2 = Data * 1.1
Data3 = Data * 2 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Month':MonthNumber, 'Data':Data})
Summary = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Month'],values='Data'],aggfunc=[np.sum,np.var])
```

so that the wrapper function looks like:

```
def summarywrapper(MonthNumber,Data,**kwargs):
   df = pd.DataFrame({'Month':MonthNumber, 'Data':Data})
   Summary = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Month'],values='Data'],aggfunc=[kwar1,kwarg2,etc])
   return Summary
```

**kwargs would contain any number of parameters like mean, len, variance that I want to supply

Also I want to be able to supply any random number of arrays like Data2, Data3 instead of just two arrays like shown in example.

How do I achieve supplying the variable number of arrays to the "SummaryFunction" and variable number of parameters that I want to calculate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear what is your input, but in Python functions are [first-class objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245192/what-are-first-class-objects) and may be passed as function argument.

Sample implementation using *args may look like:

```
def summarywrapper(MonthNumber, Data, *args):
   df = pd.DataFrame({'Month':MonthNumber, 'Data':Data})
   Summary = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Month'],values='Data'],aggfunc=args)
   return Summary
```

With sample usage:

```
summarywrapper(monthNumber, data, np.sum, np.var)
```

Here, functions itself are passed as [variadic arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).