# Python passing parameters as part of the function code

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 functions as follows:

```
def test1(var):
    return var*2

def test2(var):
    return var*4
```

I want to pass a variable to form part of the code, something like below:

```
var='test2'
def new_test(var,4):
    return var(4)
```

And I expect the output to be 16 (i.e. output from test2)

In excel, it is achievable via the function of =indirect(...). Is there any way to achieve that in Python?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't do `command=test2`?

Comment: @user2357112 Hello user2357112, it is because my current problem has to do with creating a function that takes an argument which will form part of the script within the function. I just revised my codes above for further clarity.

Comment: In the above case, I have a new function that takes an argument (var) which will either be test1 or test2. And inside the function of new_test, it is written in a way that the argument (var) will either be test1 or test2.

Comment: I'm still not seeing anything here that requires you to use a string instead of the actual function object.

Comment: user2357112, do you mean that in this case I can simply type test1 (as an object without single quotation) as an argument passing into the new_test 
as follows: print(new_test(test2,4))

Comment: Yeah, pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, instead of this:

```
var = 'test2'

def new_test(var, 4):
    return var(4)
```

You can do this directly:

```
var = test2

def new_test(var, 4):
    return var(4)
```

Functions are [first class objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/245192/674039) in Python.