# can anyone explain this I am aware of functionality of decorators but still not getting the output

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def c(f):
    def inner(*args, **kargs):
        inner.co += 1
        return f(*args, **kargs)
    inner.co = 0
    return inner
@c
def fnc():
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fnc()
    fnc()
    fnc()
    print(fnc.co)
```

please explain the final output: `3`
I am aware of the functionality of decorators but I'm still not getting the output.

Answer (score 4):

First, let's unpack what the decorator syntax does. When you write this:

```
@c
def fnc():
    pass
```

… it's equivalent to this:

```
def fnc():
    pass
fnc = c(fnc)
```

Now look at what `c` does: It creates a new function, named `inner`, and sets `inner.co` to 0, and returns `inner` to be used in place of `fnc`. So, now your code is equivalent to this:

```
def fnc():
    pass
def inner(*args, **kargs):
    inner.co += 1
    return fnc(*args, **kargs)
inner.co = 0
fnc = inner
```

So, when you call `fnc()` three times, you're calling `inner` each time. So it increments `inner.co` three times. And since `inner` and `fnc` are the same thing, `inner.co` and `fnc.co` are the same thing. So `print(fnc.co)` prints 3.

Answer (score 0):

In python, functions are "first class objects" (See [What are "first class" objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245192/what-are-first-class-objects)). This means you can set attributes on them. You define your function `fnc` here, and the decorator `c` adds a property to that function object `fnc.co`. Its a little weird that the `inner.co = 0` initialization is done after the wrapping function is declared, but since `inner` won't get called until after the `co` property is defined it doesn't matter. Then in `inner` the `co` property gets incremented each time the function is called.

Comment: still didnt get you,how printing   ' fnc.co ' is giving us 3,As each time we are calling c(f) inner.co is initialized to 0

Comment: c only gets run once. `inner()` is what is being called 3 times

Comment: How is it weird that the `inner.co = 0` is done after the function is declared? When else could you do it? Before the function is declared, there is no function to set attributes on; you'd just get an `UnboundLocalError`.