# Avoid if else to instantiate a class - python

Tags: python, design-patterns, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I want to create an object of a class based on value of a field.

For eg:

```
if r_type == 'abc':
                return Abc()
            elif r_type == 'def':
                return Def()
            elif r_type == 'ghi':
                return Ghi()
            elif r_type == 'jkl':
                return Jkl()
```

What is a pythonic way to avoid if else here. I was thinking to create a dictionary with r_type being key and classname being value, and do a get of the value and instantiate, is it a proper way, or there is something better idiomatic way in python?

Comment: what about r_type is neither of them?

Comment: It should throw an exception.

Comment: state it, and give example of it, otherwise you'll need to write another if :>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that classes are [first class objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245192/what-are-first-class-objects) in python, and use a dictionary to access the classes you want to create:

```
classes = {'abc': Abc,    # note: you store the object here
           'def': Def,    #       do not add the calling parenthesis
           'ghi': Ghi,
           'jkl': Jkl}
```

then create the class like this:

```
new_class = classes[r_type]()  # note: add parenthesis to call the object retreived
```

If your classes require parameters, you can place them like in normal class creation:

```
new_class = classes[r_type](*args, *kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3):

Or `dict.get(..)` (thanks for the edit Eran Moshe):

```
classes = {'abc': Abc,
           'def': Def,
           'ghi': Ghi,
           'jkl': Jkl}


new_class = classes.get(r_type, lambda: 'Invalid input')()
```

Answer (score 2):

Best way to this use dict, because complexity of list key operation is constant, it will handle dynamic operation as well.

```
cf = {
    'abc': Abc,
    'def': Def,
    'ghi': Ghi,
    'jkl': Jkl,
}
r_type = input('value:')
class_obj = cf.get(r_type, None)
if class_obj:
   class_obj()
```