# How to conditionally alias a method in a python class

Tags: python, class, methods, alias

Suppose a class `myClass` has two method definitions `_call1` and `_call2`, but only one of them should be used depending on a parameter passed when the object is instantiated, and a specific alias `call` is given for the chosen method. How to program this? A minimum example is shown below.

The reason behind this code is that I would like to avoid the overhead of having an `if-else` statement with two possible `return`s inside a single `call` method. Another option would be to create two different possible classes based on `cond_param`, but I'd rather avoid that.

```py
class myClass:
    def __init__(self, cond_param):
        self.cond_param = cond_param
        # depending on the value of the conditional parameter `cond_param`,
        # a method named `call` will be assigned to one of the methods
        # defined below
        if self.cond_param not in [1, 2]:
            return ValueError
        if self.cond_param == 1:
            call = _call1
        else
            call = _call2

    def _call1(self):
        return "call 1!"

    def _call2(self):
        return "call 2!"

obj1 = myClass(1)
print(obj1.call()) # should print "call 1!"

obj2 = myClass(2)
print(obj2.call()) # should print "call 2!"
```

Comment: Use a dictionary? `calls = {1: _call1, 2: _call2}` => `call = calls[cond_param]`.

Comment: If so, this is duplicate of [Avoid if else to instantiate a class - python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51627294/5821790)?

Comment: Is the dictionary an attribute of the class? And can `call` be defined inside `__init__`? The example given in the question is not a working example. It fails because inside `__init__`, `_call1` and `_call2` are undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid if-else with a dictionary.

You need to use `self.` to be able to reference something everywhere in the class. Also, you should use `raise` to raise an error, not `return` which would return the error class itself.

Fixing your code

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self, cond_param):
        self.cond_param = cond_param
        # depending on the value of the conditional parameter `cond_param`,
        # a method named `call` will be assigned to one of the methods
        # defined below
        self._calls = {1: self._call1, 2: self._call2} 
        self.call = self._calls.get(cond_param, self._callErr)

    def _call1(self):
        return "call 1!"

    def _call2(self):
        return "call 2!"
    
    def _callErr(self):
        raise  ValueError

obj1 = myClass(1)
print(obj1.call()) # should print "call 1!"

obj2 = myClass(2)
print(obj2.call()) # should print "call 2!"

obj3 = myClass(3)
print(obj3.call()) # should raise ValueError
```

gives

```
call 1!
call 2!
Traceback (most recent call last):

    ...

ValueError
```

as expected.