# function without () in useState (react hook)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When I pass function parameter to useState() like this:

```
const [testA, setTestA] = useState(returnTestA());  // run every rendering
const [testB, setTestB] = useState(returnTestB); // run only mount
```

- function with () is run every rendering
- but function without () is run only first rendering(mount)

It is my whole code: (`info.js`)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

let count = 0;

const returnTestA = () => {
  count++;
  console.log("test A: " + count);
  return "test";
};

const returnTestB = () => {
  count++;
  console.log("test B: " + count);
  return "test";
};

const Info = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [testA, setTestA] = useState(returnTestA());  // run every rendering
  const [testB, setTestB] = useState(returnTestB); // run only mount

  const onChangeName = e => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input name="name" value={name} onChange={onChangeName} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <b>Name:</b> {name}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Info;
```

the result is:

1. just npm start:
   [image: npm_start]
2. type something in input:
   [image: type_something]

Why It happened?? And what is the best practice?

Comment: `()` after a reference to a function means to **call the function immediately** and use the return value in the containing expression. Without `()`, the reference to the function is itself the value of the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the official explanation here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state

```
const [testB, setTestB] = useState(returnTestB);
```

It is similar with:

```
const [testB, setTestB] = useState(() => returnTestB());
```

You pass a function to the `useState()` method as the parameter, this function will only run once when mount.

But for

```
const [testA, setTestA] = useState(returnTestA());
```

You pass a computed object to `useState()` as the parameter, this object will be computed every time when rendering.

Comment: Thank you! And this document is helpful to understand. 

https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Answer (score 1):

it does not about react
it's about JavaScript

here is some example

```
test.js
const testFunc = () => console.log('1');
```

if we define testFunc and load test.js
that doesn't mean trigger `testFunc`

also we can pass `testFunc` as parameter
it's called *first class citizen(object)*

now let's dive to your code

```
 const [testA, setTestA] = useState(returnTestA());  // run every rendering
  const [testB, setTestB] = useState(returnTestB)
```

1. `useState(returnTestA())`.
`returnTestA()` mean is trigger(call) `returnTestA` and pass *result* of `returnTeatA` function into `useState`

**pass value**

2. `useState(useState(returnTestB))`.
`returnTestB` mean is pass *function without trigger* into `useState`.
perhaps `useState` call that

**pass function**

> you wanna know more deatil about *first class citizen(object)*
>   this link must helps you about [What are "first class" objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245192/what-are-first-class-objects)

Answer (score 1):

`returnTestA()` **calls the function.**

`returnTestA` **return its value.**

```
let a = function() {
    return 'test';
};
```

> so when you write `a()` it calls the function and return its value while
>   `a` simply means *'test'*.