# Getting TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable this error during API creation

Tags: python, django, api

```py
def operator_logincheck_web(request, email=None):

    data = json.loads
    email = data['email']
    email = email.lower()
    password = data['password']
    if Operator.objects.filter(email = email).count() > 0:
        if Operator.objects.filter(email = email, password = password).count() > 0:
            loginobj = Operator.objects.get(email = email, password = password)
            send_data = {'status':"1", 'msg':"Login Successfull", 'user_id':str(loginobj.id)}
        else:
            send_data = {'status':"0", 'msg':"Incorrect Password"}
    else:
        send_data = {'status':"0", 'msg':"Incorrect Email"}
            
    return JsonResponse(send_data)
```

But geting this error on terminal   File "/home/sumit/Cricket/CricketApp/views.py", line 1443, in operator_logincheck_web
email = data['email']
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Comment: How exactly are you expecting `data = json.loads` to work?

Answer (score 1):

Well, [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) is a function, You've assigned it back to the variable call `data` and you're looking `email` property from it. You can find payload from the `request` object in this way,

```py
data: dict = request.data
```

---

**LEARN FROM MISTAKES**

Every data in a Python program is ***represented by objects or relations between objects***.

This is what Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) describe about Objects.

> Objects are Python’s abstraction for data. All data in a Python program is represented by objects or by relations between objects. (In a sense, and in conformance to Von Neumann’s model of a “stored program computer”, code is also represented by objects.)

Python’s functions are first-class objects. Which mean, (Ref: [Dan Bader](https://dbader.org/blog/python-first-class-functions))

> You can assign them to variables, store them in data structures, pass them as arguments to other functions, and even return them as values from other functions.

and Python support Higher-order functions. Which mean, (Ref: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function))

> A higher-order function is a function that does at least one of the following, takes one or more functions as arguments (i.e. procedural parameters) or returns a function as its result.

```py
>>> import json
>>> string_json = '{"key": "value"}'
>>> json.loads(string_json)
{'key': 'value'}
>>> 
>>> data = json.loads
>>> type(data)
function
>>> 
>>> data(string_json)
{'key': 'value'}
```

I hope you can understand what's going on here, if not comment here. You can learn lot of things related to the above concepts from [Primer on Python Decorators](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/) article.

References:-

- [Python’s Functions Are First-Class](https://dbader.org/blog/python-first-class-functions)
- [Higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function)
- [Objects, values and types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types)
- [What are "first class" objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245192/what-are-first-class-objects)