# What is first-class object mean in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Resource Monitor is First-Class Object as described by Snowflake documentation ; i didn't understand what first class mean,what exactly first-class object mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are "first class" objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245192/what-are-first-class-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"First class object" simply means that your object exists independently.

According to the answer here ([What are "first class" objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245192/what-are-first-class-objects)), a first class object is an object that can be "dynamically created, destroyed, [...]"