# What does it mean to pass a function to another function?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def print_function(values, test):
    for x in values:
        print('f(', x,')=', test(x), sep='')


def poly(x):
    return 2 * x**2 - 4 * x + 2


print_function([x for x in range(-2, 3)], poly)
```

I understand what the `poly` function does. What I don't understand is the `test(x)`? What does this do and where is the connection to the `poly` function?

Comment: Functions are first class member, poly is passed as the argument to test, so when the function calls test it is really calling poly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are "first class" objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245192/what-are-first-class-objects)

Comment: Besides the above answers, you could try to run here - https://pythontutor.com/ to see the visual running steps.

Comment: You could add this line after `for loop` -  `print(f' test: {test}  & {type(test}} ')`  to confirm your understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, functions can be stored in other variables and then called as functions themselves.

Example

```
def myfunction():
        print('hello')
    
myfunction() #prints hello
    
alias_myfunction = myfunction # store function object in other variable
    
alias_myfunction() #prints hello as well

# use id to test if myfunction and alias_myfunction point to same object.
print(id(myfunction) == id(alias_myfunction))
```

Output

```
hello
hello
True
```

Both `myfunction` and `alias_myfunction` store the reference to the function object

This can be confirmed using `id`

In this particular case

```
# values -> [x for x in range(-2, 3)]
# test -> poly
def print_function(values, test):
    for x in values:
        print('f(', x,')=', test(x), sep='') 
        # When test(x) is called, it is essentially calling poly(x)    

def poly(x):
    return 2 * x**2 - 4 * x + 2
    
print_function([x for x in range(-2, 3)], poly)
```